# Workflow to check Appoval Status and run

Tags: workflow, tasks, approval-process, approval

I would like to create a workflow that checks the status of the OOB Approval workflow and runs if the task is approved. What is the if condition I need for this?

Comment: you can create second workflow and edit the Approval workflow where you will start the second WF after it will be approved before the first WF ends...

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: Haven't used OOB approver workflows, always do my own, but from what the question is asking, the IF condition would be:

"IF [_ModerationStatus] is equal to "Approved" > Do something."

You could also have "Wait for [_ModerationStatus] is equal to "Approved" > then do something.

I believe _ModerationStatus is the internal field name of the OOB Approval Status column. But you might be able to find it in your workflow as its display name.

I would also have the workflow to start when an item is created so that it's waiting for that field to equal "Approved" and then it will do its thing.

Hope this helps.